# Vue 3 (composition API) get array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I'm learning javascript and vue.js 3 composition API.
My question is I simply want to get an array length and render at

.
The array name : "getForms"

```
<script>.....
const forms_length = computed(() =>  getForms.value.length)

<template>....
<p> {{form_length}} </p>
```

I get an error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"

why? and what I should do?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: could you show us where `getForms` is

Comment: Thank you Ifaruki! It's coming from pinia, `import {useFormsStore} from '../store/forms'` and `const getForms = computed(() => { return store.forms})` if I create an array like `const getForm = computed(() => [ {id: 1, name: "aaa" }, { id: 2, name: "bbb"}, { id: 1, name: "ccc" }, {id: 1, name: "ddd" }, ])` it works....

Comment: The question should contain all the relevant code. You're still missing the line that defines `store`. Even if it's correct, it's specific to what store.forms is. The error means that  store.forms is possibly undefined, or it could refer to another array. The error mentions a promise, but there's no promise in the code. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry Estus Flask, This is first time I've posted, actually created my account. I'll be careful next time. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the computed property this way

```
<template>
  <p>Array length: {{ formsLength}}</p>
</template>
<script>
  import { computed } from 'vue'
  import {useFormsStore} from '../store/forms'
  setup() {
    const { store } = useFormsStore()
    // if the store.forms array is undefined or not ready,
    // then it returns an empty array
    const getForms = computed(() => { return store.forms || []})
    const formsLength = computed(() => getForms.value.length)

    return {
      formsLength
    }
  }
</script>
```